# 22.04 crashes randomly but regularly

Tags: 22.04, crash

I recently upgraded to 22.04. Previously I was using 20.4 and windows 10 in a dual boot system, where I experienced no crashes in windows and rarely a crash in ubuntu. Since the upgrade I experience crashes daily, sometimes several times a day.

The crashes are complete freezes, nothing works. I cant move the mouse or open a terminal, I can only shut down the computer by pressing the power button.

The only recent hardware changes I made are a adding 2x16 to my 2x8 GB RAM and adding a new SSD. I already tried adding another swap file of 64 GB because the *journalctl -u systemd-oomd* command returned out of memory issues before crashes but I still experience crashes. After that I disabled the systemd-oomd, however I still experience crashes but now without the out of memory entries in the *journalctl -u systemd-oomd*.

I am running psensor basically the whole time and the temperatures of CPU or GPU never reach any critical values. The crashes also **dont** appear more often during taxing things like video games, to me it seems completely random.

Is there any procedure I can follow to single out the reasons for my crashes ? I really love ubuntu and dont want to go back to windows but if I cant fix this I dont know what I can do.
I am happy to provide more information if that is helpful.

Comment: The single most important thing when troubleshooting is logs - so please provide log output. Please provide the last 100 lines of `/var/log/syslog` before a crash. Also, since you mentioned `systemd-oomd`, it would seem the system is running out of memory. You should setup some CPU and memory monitoring solution to get these metrics as well.

Comment: Could it be a hardware failure? When installing the new chips you may have accidentally unseated another memory stick, or not pressed the new ones properly into place. An out- of-memory situation is rarely a sudden complete freeze - before that, you will notice the mouse stuttering, the fan starting up, etc.

Comment: Memory problems after adding new memory is a clue.

Comment: For starters, please provide output of `htop`, as well as output from this command: `ps -ax -eo user,pid,pcpu:5,pmem:5,rss:8=R-MEM,vsz:10=V-MEM,tty:6=TTY,stat:5,bsdstart:7,bsdtime:7,args | (read h; echo "$h"; sort -nr -k 4) | head "-15" | less -SEX` - to see if anything consumes large amounts of memory.

Comment: And yes, double check your memory - try and switch back to either 2x8 or 2x16 and report the results - then you should be able to isolate any memory issues as well.

Comment: Thank you for tips guys, turns out my motherboard didnt get along with the new memory due to a rather old BIOS version. I updated the BIOS and it hasnt crashed yet

Comment: I am having the same problem in 20.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So even after the BIOS update it was still crashing every now and then, lately its gotten so bad that I could not use my computer anymore. I also tried swapping my ubuntu with a disk that still contained windows 10 which also crashed.

After a lot of troubleshooting it turned out that my BIOS setting for the DRAM voltage was set to AUTO, which apparently delivered 1.2V to my RAM instead of the 1.35V it actually needed. Changing the setting from auto to fixed 1.35V fixed the issue and its been completely stable since then.

Maybe this helps someone else in the future

Comment: First of all, thanks for sharing the solution after you found the issue.

May I ask where you change this setting? Is this in that startup BIOS or somewhere on Ubuntu. Thanks in advance!